# Count is displaying one only row despite multiple rows in database

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  `urgency`='1' THEN 1 END) AS verylow,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  `urgency`='2' THEN 1 END) AS low,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  `urgency`='3' THEN 1 END) AS standard,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  `urgency`='4' THEN 1 END) AS high,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  `urgency`='5' THEN 1 END) AS critical,
    tbl_users.userName
FROM 
    notes, tbl_users 
WHERE 
    notes.responsible = tbl_users.userID
    AND project_id = '4413' 
    AND (notes.status = 'Ongoing' OR notes.status = 'Not started')
```

and the output is:

```
verylow   low   standard   high   critical    userName
5          1       2         1        1        Nick
```

However this is wrong because i have multiple users in the database who have assigned tasks. and it looks like this in my database:

```
urgency userName
3       Nick
5       Nick
4       Nick
3       James
1       James
1       Nick
2       Nick
1       James
1       Nick
1       Nick
```

Any idea why it doesn't count the urgency for the other user and how many different urgencies he has?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is not entirely correct. If you would turn on MySQL mode [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by), you'd get a warning, because you are selecting a column that is not in the `GROUP BY` clause without applying an aggregation function. So you need a [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) clause.

The entire query should look like so:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  `urgency`='1' THEN 1 END) AS verylow,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  `urgency`='2' THEN 1 END) AS low,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  `urgency`='3' THEN 1 END) AS standard,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  `urgency`='4' THEN 1 END) AS high,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  `urgency`='5' THEN 1 END) AS critical,
    tbl_users.userName
FROM 
    notes, tbl_users 
WHERE 
    notes.responsible = tbl_users.userID
    AND project_id = '4413' 
    AND (notes.status = 'Ongoing' OR notes.status = 'Not started')
GROUP BY tbl_users.userName;
```

Comment: Can not believe i've didn't test that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With `COUNT` you aggregate your rows. As there is no `GROUP BY` clause, you aggregate them to one row (rather than, say a row per user).

You are selecting `userName`. Which? As you select only one row, the DBMS picks one arbitrarily.